# Web admin panel for embedded Linux IoT devices

Tags: networking, software

Devices like routers always have a web-based administrative interface that allows you to configure many aspects of the device from a web browser. Obviously, this is essentially a web server running on the embedded devices, where requests to the web site carry out different tasks.

I was wondering whether there was a free (both for personal and commercial use) web admin interface that can be installed on embedded devices and allows pages to be added/customised.

Comment: Could you [edit] with some more details on the exact type of control you want from the interface? I suspect the answer might be *build it yourself*, but I can't confidently say that without a little more info. Once you've edited, I'll see if I can answer with a 'build it yourself' idea, if that's useful to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This mostly depends on how much resources your embedded device has.

For example, on ESP8266 devices your options are limited to your own application and C (possibly Lua) programming. There are no resources to run anything else.

On a devices like Onion Omega2 with 32Mb flash and 128Mb RAM you can install LuCi (thx!) from OpenWRT, and add more pages using a scripting language like Lua or Python.

Finally on a larger devices like Raspberry PI Zero with 512+Mb RAM and multi-gigabyte storage you can use something like Webmin.

Answer (score 7):

Many of these *are already* based on a script-extensible free program, for example LuCI which is a packaged option in distributions of OpenWRT and perhaps other Linuxes intended for routers.

OpenWRT web interface documentation is at:

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/webinterface.overview